# creating preg_match using xpath in php

Tags: php, regex, dom, xpath, domxpath

I am trying to get the contents using XPATH in php.

```
<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-37'>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<div style="text-align: center;">
Hi
</div></div></div>
```

I am using below php code to get the output.

```
 $dom = new DOMDocument;
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 $dom->loadHTML($html);
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $xpath->registerPhpFunctions('preg_match');
 $regex = 'post-(content|[a-z]+)';
 $items = $xpath->query("div[ php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', @class) > 0]");
 dd($items);
```

It returns output as below

```
DOMNodeList {#580 
+length: 0 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be delimited? Try `$regex = '/post-(content|[a-z]+)/';`

Comment: sorry typo from my side.. I used  $regex = '/post-(content|[a-z]+)/'; in code

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/4JIWRt), you do not need regex.

Comment: yeah.. But I am looking for class which starts with **post-** and contains **content*. As I mentioned in the above code, I am using above regex because some will have as <div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-37'> ans some will have as <div class='post-content' id='post-body-37'>. I need to parse both options. If you look at the first one, it contains two classes **post-body entry-content* and if you look at the second one, it contains only one class **post-conten**. I need to get through this also.

Comment: Good, so you can use [`$xp->query('//div[starts-with(@class,"post-") and contains(@class, "content")]');`](https://ideone.com/l9r4fG).

Comment: got it.. thanks.. but as a concern if i need to use regex how can i use???

Comment: I will post the corrected code.

Comment: @karthick: Thank you for a nice question, let's live and learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple task like this - getting the `div` nodes with `class` attribute starting with `post-` and containing `content`, you should be using regular simple XPath queries:

```
$xp->query('//div[starts-with(@class,"post-") and contains(@class, "content")]');
```

Here,
 - `//div` - get all `div`s that...
 - `starts-with(@class,"post-")` - have "class" attribute  starting with "post-"
 - `and` - and...
 - `contains(@class, "content")` - contain "content" substring in the `class` attribute value.

To use the `php:functionString` you need to register the `php` namespace (with `$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");`) and the [PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php) (to register them all use `$xp->registerPHPFunctions();`).

For complex scenrios, when you need to analyze the values even deeper, you may want to create and register your own functions:

```
function example($attr) {
    return preg_match('/post-(content|[a-z]+)/i', $attr) > 0;
}
```

and then inside XPath:

```
$divs = $xp->query("//div[php:functionString('example', @class)]");
```

Here, `functionString` passes the string contents of `@class` attribute to the `example` function, not the object (as would be the case with `php:function`).

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/DDiMTB):

```
function example($attr) {
    return preg_match('/post-(content|[a-z]+)/i', $attr) > 0;
}
$html = <<<HTML
<body>
<div class='post-body entry-content' id='post-body-37'>
<div style="text-align: left;">
<div style="text-align: center;">
Hi
</div></div></div>
</body>
HTML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED|LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xp->registerPHPFunctions('example');
$divs = $xp->query("//div[php:functionString('example', @class)]");
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo $div->nodeValue;    
}
```

See also a nice article about the using of PhpFunctions inside XPath in [*Using PHP Functions in XPath Expressions*](http://www.cowburn.info/2009/10/23/php-funcs-xpath/).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working version with the different advices you get in comments:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// you need to register the namespace "php" to make it available in the query
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath"); 
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions('preg_match');

// add delimiters to your pattern
$regex = '~post-(content|[a-z]+)~';

// search your node anywhere in the DOM tree with "//"
$items = $xpath->query("//div[php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', @class)>0]");

var_dump($items);
```

Obviously, this kind of pattern is useless since you can get the same result with available XPATH string functions like `contains`.

Comment: does `>0` mean that if it matches `do something` and if not ignore it?